# Difference between mysql, mysql-server, mysql-client in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql

I've installed `mysql`, `mysql-server` or `mysql-client` on Linux. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 9):

The mysql-client package allows you to connect to a MySQL server. It will give you the "mysql" command-line program.

The mysql-server package allows you to run a MySQL server which can host multiple databases and process queries on those databases. It will give you the MySQL daemon, a.k.a. mysqld.

The "MySQL" package probably includes both of the above.

If you just need to connect to a remote server and run queries, install just mysql-client. If you need to host a database, install the client and server.

Answer (score 3):

The `mysql` package in Fedora is the client libraries and configuration files. `mysql-client` is the `mysql` CLI client. `mysql-server` is the MySQL server and initscript. `mysql-devel` is the files required to build against the client libraries.

Answer (score 1):

They are the various binaries that are distributed with MySQL. The server, naturally, listens for connections and processes them. mysql-client lets you interact with a MySQL database from the command line, and mysql is another name under which mysql-client is found.